# gitolite + cgit: No repositories found

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs, gitolite, cgit

I've set up and configuered [`gitolite`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) and wish to configure the [`cgit`](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit) web interface to it.

### Problem:

When browsing a directory using `cgit` I get the error:

> No repositories found

### Setup

When a new repository is created `gitolite` creates a corresponding directory to it under `/home/git/repositories` automagically. `cgit` is [configuered](http://hjemli.net/git/cgit/tree/cgitrc.5.txt) to read these repositories using:

```
project-list=/home/git/projects.list 
scan-path=/home/git/repositories
```

The problem is that these repositories doesn't seem to be *bare* repositories. If I instead manually clone one of these repositories using

```
git clone --bare user@server:repo
```

it seems to work. I really don't want to do this manually every time a new repository is checked in. Why aren't the repositories created by `gitolite` *bare* already? How can I automate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out - after trying to verify it several times - this is just a file system rights issue. After trying

```
chown -R www-data:www-data repositories/repo
```

to force ownership into my apache user running `cgit`, the repository shows up in the web interface.

The proper solution is to add the apache user to the `git` group and change the value `umask` in `.gitolite.rc` to

```
$REPO_UMASK=0027
```

Note: with [Gitolite V3 or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html), that would be ([see doc](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rc.html)):

```
$UMASK=0027
```

Comment: It might be better to just do this via the group, so that apache doesn't have write access in the repository. (That is, `chown -R <gitolite-user>:www-data repositories/repo` and fill in the rest.)

Answer (score 0):

It was similar with permission issue i encountered before.
I used a scripts to fix permission of git repositories.

script: fix_perm_cgit.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
reponame="$1"
if [ ! -d "$reponame" ]; then
   echo "missign repo_name"
   exit 1
fi


find "$reponame" -type d | while read fn ; do chmod og+rx $fn ; echo "d-> $fn" ; done
find "$reponame" -type f | while read fn ; do chmod og+r $fn ; echo "f-> $fn" ; done
```